# Asking a very similar question

Tags: discussion

I have a question regarding etiquette. I am having a problem importing a [CMake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) native project into [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29). I have already done the steps in the accepted answer in Stack Overflow question *[Importing a CMake project into Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645575)*.

However, while the CMake, [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29), makeinstall, ./executeable [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) works from the commandline, I cannot get the project to build in Eclipse. Eclipse cannot find the correct paths to the `include` or `libs` folders, even though I try to convince her with menu *Properties* -> *General C++*, *Make Project* or *Include Libs and Symb*...

If I were to post a new question, I would have basically the same title "Importing a CMake native project into Eclipse". The posting tips say I should not re-ask a question.  Essentially, if another person throws a question and someone catches it, I might like to re-throw the question. Though it might have solved some peoples' problem, it fell short for me.

Should I try to come up with a new question with slightly different subject, or comment (unavailable) on the original?

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake) It doesn't actually work. To my surprise, I cannot run the testproject executable doing

```
testrunprojectdir$ ./testproject
```

It fails with linking errors. I must run it from the repository top -1 directory specifying the full path from there, like:

```
repositoryRoot$ A/B/testrunprojectdir/testproject
```

This is possibly due to an in-source build configuration. For our project, the directory from which CMake, Make and executables are run cannot be varied.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can state specific ways in which your situation differs from that of the person who posted the prior question (other than getting a different result), there's a problem. Your question will be 'too localized', as it is a description of a problem entirely specific to your personal circumstances, and no one is going to be able to guess those circumstances and answer.

As for the linking problem, why don't you post a question that includes the complete text of the 'linkage error', and someone will very likely answer by explaining LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and then you'll know what's amiss in Eclipse as well? It has nothing to do with 'not finding include or lib folders.'